# Get two <ul>s horizontally aligned in tabs

Tags: html, css

Please check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/3743/)**. I have trouble getting two unorder lists horizontally aligned in jqueryUI tabs. I've tried `float:left` `display:inline` on the `<ul>` but to no effect. Can anyone give me some ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
         <p>
           <div id="pricing-table" class="pricing-table">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="heading">Bronze</li>
                                <li class="price">£20</li>
                                <li>Starter package</li>
                                <li>15 Projects</li><li>40%</li>
                                <li class="action">Buy Now</li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="feature">
                                <li class="heading">Silver</li>
                                <li class="price">£60</li>
                                <li>Intermediate package</li>
                                <li>20 Projects</li><li>30%</li>
                                <li class="action">Buy Now</li>
                            </ul>                                
                        </div> 

            <div style="clear:both"></div>                                
        </p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
body {
   background-color: #eef;     
}
#tabs {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}    

.pricing-table {display:table;}
.pricing-table ul{ 
    border-width: 1px; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: #cccccc; 
    border-radius: 7px; 
    margin: 2px; 
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
    list-style: none; 
    float:left;
    padding: 5px; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
} 
.pricing-table ul li{ 
    padding: 4px; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    border-width: 0px; 
    border-style: dotted; 
    border-color: #CCCCCC; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    border-bottom-width: 1px; 
    font-size: 13px; line-height:26px; } 
.pricing-table li:nth-child(odd){ 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
} 
.pricing-table ul .heading{ 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    background-color: #404554; 
    font-size: 15px; height:80px; 
} 
.pricing-table ul .price{ 
    color: #636363; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-size: 17px; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `display: table-cell`? See http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/

Comment: try display:inline on `ul li` elements

Comment: You don't have a width declared for `.pricing-table`, so your ul's property of `width:50%` isn't going to work. `width:50%` means 50% of the parent. So right now they are just filling the width. You'll also need to add `display: inline-block;` to `pricing-table ul;` and reduce width from 50% to something less to account for padding/margins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

### [Solution 1.](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p3sfy/3761/)

Remove `float:left` and add `display:table-cell` to `.pricing-table ul`

### [Solution 2](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p3sfy/3760/)

Remove `display:table` from `.pricing-table` and remove `width:50%;` from `.pricing-table ul`

### [Solution 3b (full width, preferred)](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p3sfy/3759/)

Remove `float:left` and add `display:table-cell` to `.pricing-table ul`, add `width:100%` to `.pricing-table`

Comment: Solution 3: Add `width: 100%;` to `.pricing-table` and add `display: inline-block;` to `.pricing-table ul` and change `width: 50%;` in `.pricing-table ul` to `width: 46%;`.

Comment: @TylerH, good call also- I can add above, or feel free to make a seperate answer- its just as valid a solution

Comment: @SW4 I make no claims about the quality of solution 3 :-) I just know it "works". Feel free to add it to your answer if you are so inclined.

Comment: @SW4 Nice modification!

Answer (score 1):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jFqw6/)?

My solution is changing `.pricing-table { display: table; }` to `display: flex;`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put the list horizentally , I think this way can answer you :

css:

```
ul li {float:left;}
```